# Postman form encoded file upload not working with retrofit

Tags: android, api, postman, retrofit2

I have been trying to replicate the below request with Retrofit2. The request is adding an image file as in the screenshot below.

[image]

So far I have tried the following Retrofit requests

1.

```
 @Multipart
        @POST
        public Call<I3ClaimsResponse> postDocument(@Url String url, @Header("Authorization") String token,  @Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Part("files") RequestBody file);

 RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(pdfFile, MediaType.parse("application/pdf"));
```

2. ```
   @Multipart
             @POST
             public Call<I3ClaimsResponse> postDocument(@Url String url, @Header("Authorization") String token,  @Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body MultipartBody body);
   ```

//Request

```
 RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(pdfFile, MediaType.parse("application/pdf"));
                            
                            MultipartBody multipartBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM).addFormDataPart("files", pdfFile.getName(), body).build();
```

3. ```
    @Multipart
                 @POST
                 public Call<I3ClaimsResponse> postDocument(@Url String url, @Header("Authorization") String token,  @Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
   ```

//Request

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(pdfFile, 
MediaType.parse("application/pdf"));

MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", 
pdfFile.getName(), body);
```